# Can I put non-program files onto a custom image through UCK?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, uck

I'm aware of the steps of using uck, but is it possible to put extra files into the image that would end up in the Persistence (like the Install Ubuntu thing). i.e a readme.txt in the user's desktop or a file that a user can use with a program out of the box?

Comment: Next time please make it clear what you're referring to. The first google result for "uck" is Kosovo Liberation Army... Quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important details about [Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/):

1. !!!PROJECT DISCONTINUED!!! [sic]
2. *Ubuntu Customization Kit is a tool that helps you customizing official Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your needs. You can add any **package** to the live system, for example language packs, or applications.* [My bold]

The answer is no.